# How to Populate nested queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a typical Project with Node.js - Express - Mongoose - MongoDB

My goal is to generate a `News` feed by calling all the recent articles of all the users that the main User follows.

**User Model**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  email: String,
  articles : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Article' }],
  follows: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

**Article Model**

```
var articleSchema = new Schema({
  _userID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
  url: String,
  summary: String,
  title: String,
  content: String,
  image_url: String,
});
```

**The Problem:**

I am trying to write a mongoose query that does the following

1. Search by userID and get a list of follows
2. populate those followers recent articles

I can figure out how to populate the follows but I do not know how to then also populate the follows's respected articles and return them in chronologically order (recent > oldest)

```
    exports.getFeed = function(req, res) {
        var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
        // mongoose query goes here
    };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need two queries.

The first query is the one you already figured out and need anyway (get the list of follows).
You basically need an array of the follows IDs and then you ask for all articles from this user array:

`.where('_userID').in(arrayOfFollowIDs)`

Hope that helps